# How do I get through Snowdin on the Genocide run on switch?

Tags: undertale

I just recently finished a Neutral route because I was trying to do genocide. I killed every monster I came across. When I found out you need to HUNT down every single monster, I tried to, and was doing pretty good until I came to snowdin. There's 3 monsters left, and I can't find a single one. I tried to google it, but all the answers that came up were for the computer. I am on a switch. Can you please help?

Comment: Is there a difference between the PC and Switch versions in that regard?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep running around, and they will ultimately appear. The more you kill them and the more the apparition rates lower, making it feels like they're not appearing anymore. If you keep on walking, they will appear, and you will be able to kill them.